# Prevent a view nested in a ScrollView from scrolling off top of screen

Tags: android, user-interface, scrollview

I have a ScrollView with a LinearLayout inside of it, the LinearLayout has several children. One of these children is a HorizontalScrollView that contains navigation options. When the app loads up, there is some content towards the top, the menu in the middle of the screen, and more content below.  I would like the menu to scroll up the screen along with the rest of the content, but when it begins to scroll off screen, lock to the top sort of like a header. If the user scrolls back down, it should stay pinned until all the content under it has scrolled, then begin scrolling again so if they scroll all the way the screen appears identical to the way it started. Right now I have this initial attempt, which seems to do nothing:

```
final View carouselMenu = rootView.findViewById(R.id.carousel_menu);
ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.main_scroll);
RelativeLayout mainContainer = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.main_root_container);

    scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {
            if (carouselMenu.getScrollY() < 0) {
                carouselMenu.setScrollY(0);
            }
        }
    });
```

setScrollY doesn't seem to set where the View is drawn like I had hoped it would. Is there a way to manually override where a particular view is placed on the screen, or a better method I haven't considered?

Comment: did u get a solution?